# How to give onblur listenter to window

Tags: javascript, window, event-listener

The Question is, 
The backgroundColor have to be "white" when you click the browser, and
it has to turn in to "lightgray" when you click somewhere outside out of the browser.
I thought I can make this happen by giving onblur listener and onfocus listener to the window object.
But it didn't work out. 
I've tried in two ways.... Does anyone know problems I have?
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add the code in a snipset instead of images

Comment: Piggybacking on Nicolas, a codeblock will be formed if you have a block of text that is indented four spaces.  You can also start a codeblock by clicking the curly braces icon (**{ }**) in the editor.

Comment: Hi @WonGyeong -- Adding your code as an image is better, but still far from preferred.  Please review [ask] -- asking well-formed and well-formatted questions ensure you'll get the best possible feedback from the community.  Happy coding!

Comment: Hello @AlexanderNied Thank you for your comment and kind instruction. This was my first time to upload question here. I will lead carefully what you linked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the document's (that is the `html` element's) style, you have to use `document.documentElement.style`, not `document.style`.

In order to detect such mistakes by yourself in the future, you should always check the console output in your browser's developer console (F12) for syntax errors or other helpfule messages,

```js
// set the initial value:
document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = document.hasFocus() ? 'yellow' : 'lightgrey';

window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
document.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
```

To

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
```

```js
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
});
```

Comment: Why do you assume OP wants to set the body's background-color? Seems to me that the intention is to set it to the document (i.e. the html element). Doesn't make a difference in most cases, but still might be needed if the body already has a transparent background image, for example, or other circumstances dictate it.